Browser testing closing when try to login on an aplication
I created a test for an application in Java. Everything was fine. I took the elements required, filled the fields but when, click on the login button it appears like a restart, there appears the message "your tests are loading" and then the testing browser closes too fast.
The console doesn't bring any errors or hints. I tried on all the browsers and the behavior was the same. I tried with assertions and logs but still the same.
Unfortunely I cant access to the application code, just trying to automate a flow for that page from my second job.
This is the test I'm trying to execute.
import loginPage from "../../pages/login/login-page";
import principalPage from "../../pages/principal/principal-page";
import purchaseOrdersPage from "../../pages/purchase-orders/purchase-orders-page";

describe('Description', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('https://sodexo.iconstruye.com/');
    })

    it('Login correct', () => {
        loginPage.typeUsername('emoreno');
        loginPage.typeCompany('sodexo');
        loginPage.typePassword('rrtfpkvo123123');
        loginPage.clickLogin();
        cy.screenshot('after_login');
        cy.wait(5000, { timeout: 30000 });

        cy.get(principalPage.elements.welcomeTitle()).should('be.visible');

        principalPage.elements.welcomeTitle().should('have.text', 'Bienvenido a Su Escritorio Sr(a). Eliezer Moreno');
        cy.wait(3000, { timeout: 30000 });
        principalPage.clickReception();
        principalPage.clickPurchaseOrder();

        cy.get(purchaseOrdersPage.elements.searchPurchOrderTitle()).should('have.text', 'Busqueda de Ordenes de Compra para Recibir');
        cy.get(purchaseOrdersPage.elements.searchPurchOrderTitle()).should('be.visible');

        cy.wait(10000, { timeout: 60000 });
    })
})

You can find the complete repository here:
https://github.com/Jer77/Cypress-e2e
Thanks in advance!
After the click on login enter to the application landing page.
